# What do you need to interact with the objects built out of red bricks?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

What spell or character do you need to interact with the red brick objects?  For the other special bricks, a message appears on the screen letting you know what type of character you need, but no message appears when you are near items built out of red bricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the Diffindo spell to work with anything that is red. You will gain this spell in your first year, after you have been to see Professor Flitwick for the first time, and completed his Charms lesson. This lesson is played after the third level of the year 5.

Diffindo can be used to cut shapes out of red walls, which you can then build into other items. To cut a shape out of a wall, make sure you have Diffindo selected on your spell wheel, then target the red wall to cast at it. You must then stand on the small glowing orange spot on the floor in front of the wall. When you are in place, an X will appear showing that you need to press X. You can now draw the outline of the shape on the wall to cut around it and release the bricks. These bricks can then be built into other objects that can help you along the way.

There are other objects around the game that are smaller than the walls but are still red. You will also need Diffindo to destroy any of these.